# SWIFT Using Stringsdict and Plural Rule

Tags: ios, swift, localization

In my iOS app on one of the screens I use a label, the text on which should change depending on the number of objects: one apple, two apple**S** and others..
I created **Localizable.stringdict** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>searches</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@search_count@</string>
    <key>search_count</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>s</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>остался %s поиск</string>
        <key>many</key>
        <string>осталось %s поиска</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>осталось %s поиска</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Later in the viewController class, I created a function

```
  private func searches(_ count: UInt) {
     let format: String = NSLocalizedString("searches", comment: "")
     let result: String = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, count)
     print(result)
  }
```

and call this function in viewDidLoad.

The application crashes at the start with error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)**.

Debbuger indicates the line where **Result** is created. As far as I understand the problem is that the **Format** is not created.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary specifies “s” as string format specifier, that is for a C string. For `UInt` (which is `NSUInteger` as Foundation C type) it should be “lu” instead (compare [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html)):

```
<key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
<string>%#@search_count@</string>
<key>search_count</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
    <string>lu</string>
    <key>one</key>
    <string>остался %lu поиск</string>
    <key>many</key>
    <string>осталось %lu поиска</string>
    <key>other</key>
    <string>осталось %lu поиска</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Indeed, it was in the format, I understood from <b>s</b> to <b>d</b> and it all worked as I wanted.

Comment: @V.Khuraskin: You are welcome! – You might consider to *accept* the answer if it solved your problem :)